# How to break a tie randomly from the highest values of a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, random

I want to return the key that has the highest value in a dictionary, and if there is a tie, to choose one of them randomly. I know how to get the max value, but can't figure out how to break a tie.

```
max(result, key = result.get)
```

This gets me the max value, but if the dictionary has a tie, then it just gives me the first one it comes across

Given the dictionary `{'banana': 3, 'apple': 2, 'cherry': 1, 'orange': 3}`

Output must either give `banana` or `orange`, but at random.

Comment: How would you get all the keys you're interested in? Can you try that first?

Answer (score 5):

First get the `max` value from the dict

```
import random
maxValue = max(result.values())
```

And then collect all the keys into `list` which are having max value using [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
keys = [key for key, value in result.items() if value == maxValue]
```

Now get the random value from `keys`

```
choice = random.choice(keys)
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Though, it is a little over my level of understanding. Is there a simpler way to write this, in a few more lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

You could build an inverse dictionary:

```
import random

d =  {'banana': 3, 'apple': 2, 'cherry': 1, 'orange': 3}

d_inv = dict.fromkeys(d.values())
for dkey, dval in d.items(): 
    d_inv.setdefault(dval, list())
    d_inv[dval].append(dkey)

m = max(d.values())
print(random.choice(d_inv[m]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` + `choice`:

```
from itertools import groupby
import random

d = {'banana': 3, 'apple': 12, 'cherry': 1, 'orange': 12}

print(random.choice(max(((k, list(g)) for k, g in groupby(sorted(d, key=d.get), key=d.get)), key=lambda x: x[0])[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `list comprehension`, `max` and `random` function:

```
import random
data = {'banana': 3, 'apple': 2, 'cherry': 1, 'orange': 3}
result = [i for i, v in data.items() if v == max(data.values())]
print (random.choice(result))

# With simple for loop and if condition
result_1 = []
for i, v in data.items():
    if v == max(data.values()):
        result_1.append(i)
print (random.choice(result_1))
```

I hope this helps and counts!

Comment: Is there a simpler or basic way to do this? Without list comprehension and just for and if loops?

Comment: You can just convert the list comprehension to a simpler form using for loops and if conditions. I have updated the answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: This keeps selecting that same one, rather then alternating answers like it should. Any fix for this? (Btw thanks for the update)

Comment: Since there are only two values having 3 -> `banana` and `orange`, randomizing has a chance of repeating the result. Every result doesn't verifies or checks the result displayed in previous run.

Comment: This totally works when using it in a new file alone. But when I try to implement this into a function, where the 'data' comes from the doctring, it keeps picking the same one, 50 times in a row. It doesn't work inside a function and I dont understant why

Comment: Modify your question or raise a new question with the problem you are facing. I request you close this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Although you cannot shuffle the entries in a dictionary, you can build a list with the keys, shuffle them, and then apply the max function:

```
import random

result = {'banana': 3, 'apple': 2, 'cherry': 1, 'orange': 3}
keys = list(result.keys())
random.shuffle(keys)
print(max(keys, key=lambda k: result[k]))
```

Both max and shuffle are fast functions.